# Unused variable warning when the variable is used

Tags: c, kerberos

I don't understand why I am getting unused variable warnings for 'version' and 'service' in the following c code. I'm also being told the variable bundle is uninitialised when I have initialised it as far as I can tell. Any insight would be appreciated:

```
int main() {

  int fd = socket(AF_INET,     /* network versus AF_LOCAL */
                  SOCK_STREAM, /* reliable, bidirectional, arbitrary payload size */
                  0);          /* system picks underlying protocol (TCP) */
  if (fd < 0) report("socket", 1); /* terminate */

  /* bind the server's local address in memory */
  struct sockaddr_in saddr;
  memset(&saddr, 0, sizeof(saddr));          /* clear the bytes */
  saddr.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* versus AF_LOCAL */
  saddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* host-to-network endian */
  saddr.sin_port = htons(80);        /* for listening */

  if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, sizeof(saddr)) < 0)
    report("bind", 1); /* terminate */

  /* listen to the socket */
  if (listen(fd, 20) < 0) /* listen for clients, up to MaxConnects */
    report("listen", 1); /* terminate */

  spc_krb5bundle_t *bundle;
  bundle->ctx = NULL;
  bundle->auth_ctx = NULL;
  bundle->ticket = NULL;

  char* service="krbtgt";
  char* version="1";

  krb5_error_code spc_krb5_server(int fd, spc_krb5bundle_t *bundle, char *service, char *version);
}
```

Thank-you.

Comment: The last line is a nested function *declaration*. Which you probably did not intend.

Comment: No, I didn't. In what way is it nested?

Comment: You want to call this function I guess. Looking at the rest of your code I suppose you should know how to call a function... It is nested in the sense that it is being declared inside the body of another function (`main`).

Comment: I have the function defined outside of main but in the same file. I thought I was just calling on the last line :(

Comment: This is the code immediately before main starts:

Comment: Do you understand the difference between a function call and its declaration?  You have a whole bunch of calls in your posted code (`memset`, `listen`, `bind`, `report`, `socket`). To call this function you need to simply `spc_krb5_server(fd, bundle, service, version);`

Comment: Thank-you Eugene. I understand now!

Comment: `spc_krb5bundle_t *bundle;` is an uninitialized pointer. You need to allocate memory for it before you start assigning values to the members. Alternatively declare it like `spc_krb5bundle_t bundle;` and pass it the the function as `&bundle`.

Answer (score 3):

This line is a function prototype.

```
  krb5_error_code spc_krb5_server(int fd, spc_krb5bundle_t *bundle, char *service, char *version);
```

You want:

```
  spc_krb5_server(fd, bundle, service, version);
```

Comment: Thank-you! I came to realise that after Eugene had mentioned the difference between calling and declaring and now I'm past the error. But thank-you for taking the time to show me exactly. Thank-you both!